# Searching content by taxonomy term

Tags: 8, search

I would like to search content depending on select menu. Something like the search box here: http://www.doyleia.com/anazitisi-ergasias 
How can I do that with drupal 8?

Comment: Please notice that requests for implementing a feature that essentially are _I want to do like in this site [link to a site]._ are off-topic for us. That is more true if the site is not running Drupal; even if the site would be running Drupal, there would not be much difference. We should try to understand which modules the site is using, and with which settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with filters in Views.

Just create a view, add filters and make them "exposed", so that visitors can choose filters themselves. Filters can be taxonomy terms, list options or open-ended fields (e.g. text field) where users can write what they are searching for.

See the [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module for providing a more user-friendly interface for `<select>` elements that accept multiple choices.